# Spring boot JPA repository committing code even if @Transactional placed in Service layer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, repository

> ***See below spring boot code***

I have used JPA repository.

1. Controller.
2. Service.
3. Repository

**BaseController**

```
package com.controller;

import com.service.StudentService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/addStudent", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> base() {


        studentService.save();

        return new ResponseEntity<String>("SUCCESS", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**StudentService.java**

```
package com.service;

import com.model.Student;
import com.repository.StudentRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service("studentService")
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Student save() {

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setFirstName("ABC");
        student.setLastName("PQR");
        studentRepository.save(student);

        int i = 10 / 0;  //Error code

        return student;
    }
}
```

**StudentRepository**

```
package com.repository;

import com.model.Student;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository("studentRepository")
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {

    public List<Student> findAll();

}
```

**Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
#maximum number of milliseconds that a client will wait for a connection
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout = 20000
#minimum number of idle connections maintained by HikariCP in a connection pool
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle= 10
#maximum pool size
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size= 10
#maximum idle time for connection
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000
# maximum lifetime in milliseconds of a connection in the pool after it is closed.
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime= 1000
#default auto-commit behavior.
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit =false

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?autoReconnect=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties..hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

> After executing save method from StudentRepository, data get inserted
>   immediately into database. no rollback or any other isolation levels are
>   working in StudentServiceImpl.java even if Error code is there.
>   I have tried to set `"spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit =true"` setting value **true**, Placed @Transaction at top of the StudentServiceImpl.java class but still it didn't worked.

Comment: what kind of error are/were you expecting here that Spring did not detect?

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need to mess with *any* hikari settings, and certainly not with autoCommit(true) as this DISABLES transactions. **Delete all these properties.**
2. Where is the "error" in your code? Spring rolls back on **unchecked exceptions** being thrown (not checked ones or errors), I cannot see that in your code.
3. What behavior do you expect? It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably beacause of Open Jpa in View behaviour.
Write the following line in your properties file:

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

take a look at [this if you want to know more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60675809/crudrepository-save-appears-to-cascade/60676334?noredirect=1#comment107352541_60676334).